# I am trying to code a function which can take two arrays of number and sorted in ascending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to code a function which can take two arrays of number and sorted in ascending order and returns it.But before that i am trying to generate random numbers in the array it look like this

```
Tips 
>> a = Array.new(5) {|i| 2*i}
=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>> b = Array.new(4) {|i| 3*i}
=> [0, 3, 6, 9]
>> merge(a, b)
=> [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9

arry =[]
a = Array.new(5)
print a
a.each do |i.to_i|
    c = 2.to_i * i.to_i
    arry.push(c)                
end
print arry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear, so i am explaining basic things.

Creating a random array (of say 5 length)

```
a1 = (1..999).to_a.sample 5
# => [403, 256, 506, 905, 283]

a2 = (1..999).to_a.sample 5
# => [992, 952, 12, 922, 660]
```

Merging them

```
b = a1 + a2
# => [403, 256, 506, 905, 283, 992, 952, 12, 922, 660]
```

Sorting it

```
b.sort!
# => [12, 256, 283, 403, 506, 660, 905, 922, 952, 992]
```